# Basic JQuery fader

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I created this simple fader in JQuery,

It's running fine except that, the first image fades twice, how do I fix that?
here is the code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  var count = 0;
  var images = ["http://kingofwallpapers.com/fantasy/fantasy-005.jpg",
                "https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/57/48/b0/5748b075637cb4e085d5d1d1b5990624.jpg",
                "http://www.mrwallpaper.com/wallpapers/Fantasy-City.jpg",
                "https://galeri14.uludagsozluk.com/855/kad%C4%B1n_1271171.jpg"];
  var image = $(".fader");

  image.css("background-image","url("+images[count]+")");

  setInterval(function(){
    image.fadeOut(500, function(){
      image.css("background-image","url("+images[count++]+")");
      image.fadeIn(500);
    });
    if(count == images.length)
    {
      count = 0;
    }
  },5000);

});
```

```css
.fader {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  z-index: -99;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fader"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
  image.css("background-image","url("+images[count]+")");
```

with

```
  image.css("background-image","url("+images[count++]+")");
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  var count = 0;
  var images = ["http://kingofwallpapers.com/fantasy/fantasy-005.jpg",
                "https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/57/48/b0/5748b075637cb4e085d5d1d1b5990624.jpg",
                "http://www.mrwallpaper.com/wallpapers/Fantasy-City.jpg",
                "https://galeri14.uludagsozluk.com/855/kad%C4%B1n_1271171.jpg"];
  var image = $(".fader");

  image.css("background-image","url("+images[count++]+")");

  setInterval(function(){
    image.fadeOut(500, function(){
      image.css("background-image","url("+images[count++]+")");
      image.fadeIn(500);
    });
    if(count == images.length)
    {
      count = 0;
    }
  },5000);

});
```

```css
.fader {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  z-index: -99;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fader"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are presenting the same image twice. You do not notice but the other images do the same thing if you increase the time. Solution create a time variable. Use this variable for when you load the image the wait time is 0, then it changes to 500.

```
var i=0;
...
image.fadeOut(i, function(){
i=500;
...
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var i=0;
  var count = 0;
  var images = ["http://kingofwallpapers.com/fantasy/fantasy-005.jpg",
                "https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/57/48/b0/5748b075637cb4e085d5d1d1b5990624.jpg",
                "http://www.mrwallpaper.com/wallpapers/Fantasy-City.jpg",
                "https://galeri14.uludagsozluk.com/855/kad%C4%B1n_1271171.jpg"];
  var image = $(".fader");

  //image.css("background-image","url("+images[count]+")");

  setInterval(function(){
    image.fadeOut(i, function(){
      i=500;
      image.css("background-image","url("+images[count++]+")");
      image.fadeIn(i);
    });
    if(count == images.length)
    {
      count = 0;
    }
  },5000);

});
```

```css
.fader {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  z-index: -99;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fader"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are more shorter version.
Set your first image as default background image with css.
And change the index of `images`.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var count = 0;
  var images = [
                "https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/57/48/b0/5748b075637cb4e085d5d1d1b5990624.jpg",
                "http://www.mrwallpaper.com/wallpapers/Fantasy-City.jpg",
                "https://galeri14.uludagsozluk.com/855/kad%C4%B1n_1271171.jpg",
                "http://kingofwallpapers.com/fantasy/fantasy-005.jpg"];
                
  var image = $(".fader");
  setInterval(function(){
      image.fadeOut(500, function(){
      image.css("background-image","url("+images[count++]+")");
      image.fadeIn(500);
    });
    if(count == images.length){count = 0}
  },5000);
});
```

```css
.fader {
  position: absolute;
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  z-index: -99;
  background-image: url("http://kingofwallpapers.com/fantasy/fantasy-005.jpg");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fader"></div>
```